# Boolean field in code

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I can't figure out how to add boolean field for the custom type I'm trying to create. When I try `'type' => 'boolean'` drupal says that there is no such type. And also, how can i use radio buttons to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are looking for is the 'list_boolean'.

```
'type' => 'list_boolean'
```